# Django, QuerySet

Tags: python, django

Всем привет. Есть три модели:

1. `Catalog` в котором есть "Каталог автошин", "Каталог автодисков" и т.д.
2. `Manufactures` (производители) внутри которого "bosch", "michelin" "motador" и т.д.
3. `Product` у которого `ForeignKey` и на `Catalog` и на
   `Manufactures`.

Задача: 
Через продукты отфильтровать производителей по каталогам. 
То есть если "bosch" и "michelin" относятся к дискам то передать их в "Каталог автодисков".

```
from django.db import models
    
    
class Catalogs(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        verbose_name = 'Каталог'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Каталоги'
    
    catalog_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Название каталога', blank=False)
    catalog_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='catalog_images', verbose_name='Картинка каталога')
    # ...
    
class Manufactures(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        verbose_name = 'Производитель'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Производители'
    
    manufacture_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Название производителя', blank=False)
    # ...
    
class Product(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        verbose_name = 'Шина'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Шины'
    
    tire_image = models.ImageField(blank=False, upload_to='tire_images', verbose_name='Картинка продукта')
    tire_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name= 'Название продукта', blank=False)
    tire_manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Производитель:', blank=False)
    tire_size = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Размер', blank=False)
    tire_load = models.CharField(verbose_name='Нагрузка', blank=False, max_length=12)
    tire_price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Цена', blank=False)
    connect_manufacture = models.ForeignKey(Manufactures, verbose_name='Выберите производителя')
    connect_catalog = models.ForeignKey(Catalogs, verbose_name='Выберите каталог')
```

Помогите решить задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала можешь создать форму для отбора в forms.py, потом во view.py делаешь функцию которая будет ловить запрос по этой форме и отдавать нужные категории.
Если хоть немножко рубишь в JS то можно сделать без форм и отдавать то что тебе надо через самодельное API, тут уже как угодно делай, либо отдавай сразу отрендеренный HTML, либо JSON готовь и уже JS-ом его отображай.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Достаём список уникальных имён всех каталогов
catalog_names = Product.objects.values_list('connect_catalog__catalog_name', flat=True).distinct()

manufactures_by_catalog = {}

# Для каждого имени каталога ищем производителей через `Product`.
for catalog_name in catalog_names:
    # Достаём список уникальных производителей из всех продуктов с категорией 'category_name'
    manufactures = Product.objects.filter(connect_catalog__catalog_name=catalog_name).values_list('connect_manufacture__manufacture_name', flat=True).distinct()
    manufactures_by_catalog[catalog_name] = list(manufactures)
```

В итоге мы получим `dict` где ключи это имена каталогов а значения это список имён производителей.